# recursive element in xsd schema

Tags: c#, xml, recursion

I am trying to make XSD for categories but it always give me this warning error 
warning : namespace '' is not available to be referenced in this schema 
Error: 'Category' was not reported 
I tried to make recursive categories with not specified level of hierarchy

and this is my XSD structure

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.tempuri.org" targetNamespace="http://www.tempuri.org" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Categories">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Category" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Category">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="parent" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Category" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The needed xml is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Categorıes>
<Category>
<Code>1</Code>
<Name>Kategori1</Name>
<Parent>0</Parent>
<Category>
<Code>11</Code>
<Name>Kategori11</Name>
<Parent>1</Parent>
<Category>
<Code>111</Code>
<Name>Kategori111</Name>
<Parent>11</Parent>
</Category>
</Category>
</Category>
<Category>
<Code>2</Code>
<Name>Kategori2</Name>
<Parent>0</Parent>
<Category>
<Code>21</Code>
<Name>Kategori21</Name>
<Parent>2</Parent>
<Category>
<Code>211</Code>
<Name>Kategori211</Name>
<Parent>21</Parent>
</Category>
<Category>
<Code>212</Code>
<Name>Kategori212</Name>
<Parent>21</Parent>
</Category>
</Category>
</Category>
</Categorıes>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The `Category` element is in namespace `http://www.tempuri.org` so you need to reference it as

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="t:Category"
            xmlns:t="http://www.tempuri.org"/>
```

Of course the namespace declaration can appear on any ancestor element; it's usual to put it on xs:schema itself.